# Issue while testing route entries using mvccontrib test helper in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, tdd, mvccontrib

I am trying to write test methods for Route entries and in my route config there were a lot of entries for different action. I am using  `MvcContrib.TestHelper` for Testing . I am new to MVC as well as TDD. Kindly help me to solve this issue. My test case is failing and what can I do to make it pass .

**Route Entry**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "X1Details",
            url: "X1/{X1ID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "X1", action = "Index", X1ID = "X1ID" }
            );
```

**X1Controller**

```
   public ActionResult Index(int? instanceID = 0,  string  InfoMsg ="")
   {
   }
```

**Test Method**

```
[Test Method]
     public void Should_Route_X1Index()
            {

                "~/X1/"
                    .ShouldMapTo<X1Controller>(action => action.Index(null, ""));

            }
```

**Error**

> Test method
>   XXX.Tests.MVCContibRouteMapTest.Should_Route_X1IndexOf
>   threw exception:  MvcContrib.TestHelper.AssertionException: Value for
>   parameter 'InfoMsg' did not match: expected '' but was ''; no value
>   found in the route context action parameter named 'InfoMsg' - does
>   your matching route contain a token called 'InfoMsg'?

Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default values don't work well with MVCContrib helper. You could modify your controller action like so:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? instanceID, string InfoMsg)
{
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
"~/X1".ShouldMapTo<X1Controller>(action => action.Index(null, null));
```

Comment: I cannot change the signature because InfoMsg must have a default value to String.Empty

Answer (score 1):

I've found this approach to work, which should allow your controllers to remain the same

```
[Test Method]
public void Should_Route_X1Index()
{
     var routeData = "~/X1/".Route();
     routeData.Values["InfoMsg "] = "";
     routeData.Values["instanceID"] = "0";
     routeData.ShouldMapTo<X1Controller>(action => action.Index(0, ""));
}
```